# How to melt into columns row results?

Tags: r, melt

From a frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2010,2010,2011,2011), stock = c("Amazon","Google","Yahoo","Google")
```

How can we melt the rows and convert into columns count results?
The expected output:

```
   stock 2010 2011
Amazon     1     0
Google     1     1
Yahoo     0     1
```

Comment: `df$one <- 1;

xtabs(one ~ stock + year, df)`

Comment: `reshape2::recast(df, stock ~ value, id.var = "stock", fun.aggregate = length)`

Answer (score 2):

```
table(rev(df))
#         year
# stock    2010 2011
#   Amazon    1    0
#   Google    1    1
#   Yahoo     0    1
```

`rev()` is to have the desired output directly, otherwise transpose with `t(table(df))`)

Or equivalently:

- `table(df[2:1])` (by [Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635580/sotos))
- `table(df$stock, df$year)` (by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang))

Comment: Or even `table(df[2:1])`

Comment: Or `table(df$stock, df$year)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(janitor)
df %>% tabyl(stock, year)                 
#>   stock 2010 2011
#>  Amazon    1    0
#>  Google    1    1
#>   Yahoo    0    1
```